# How to make dynamic links in php without eval()

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress for a web site. I am using snippets (my own custom php code) to fetch data from a database and echo that data onto my web site.

```
if($_GET['commentID'] && is_numeric($_GET['commentID'])){
      $comment_id=$_GET['commentID'];
      $sql="SELECT comments FROM database WHERE commentID=$comment_id";
      $result=$database->get_results($sql);
      echo "<dl><dt>Comments:</dt>";
      foreach($result as $item):
            echo "<dd>".$item->comment."</dd>";
      endforeach;
      echo "</dl>";
}
```

This specific page reads an ID from the URL and shows all comments related to that ID. In most cases, these comments are texts. But some comments should be able to point to other pages on my web site.

For example, I would like to be able to input into the comment-field in the database:

```
This is a magnificent comment. You should also check out <a href=\"<?php getURLtoSectionPage($commentID) ?>\">this other section</a> for more information
```

where getURLtoSectionPage() is a function I have declared in my functions.php to provide the static URLs to each section of my home page in order to prevent broken links if I change my URL pattern in the future.

I do not want to do this by using eval(), and I have not been able to accomplish this by using output buffers either. I would be grateful for any hints as to how I can get this working as safely and cleanly as possible. I do not wish to execute any custom php code, only make function calls to my already existing functions which validates input parameters.

**Update:**
Thanks for your replies. I have been thinking of this problem a lot, and spent the evening experimenting, and I have come up with the following solution.

My SQL "shortcode":

```
This is a magnificent comment. You should also check out <a href=\"[custom_func:getURLtoSectionPage:42]\">this other section</a> for more information
```

My php snippet in wordpress:

```
ob_start();
// All my code that echo content to my page comes here
// Retrieve ID from url
// Echo all page contents
// Finished generating page contents
$entire_page=ob_get_clean();
replaceInternalLinks($entire_page);
```

PHP function in my functions.php in wordpress

```
if(!function_exists("replaceInternalLinks")){
    function replaceInternalLinks($reference){
        mb_ereg_search_init($reference,"\[custom_func:([^\]]*):([^\]]*)\]");
        if(mb_ereg_search()){
            $matches = mb_ereg_search_getregs(); //get first result
            do{
                if($matches[1]=="getURLtoSectionPage" && is_numeric($matches[2])){
                    $reference=str_replace($matches[0],getURLtoSectionPage($matches[2]),$reference);
                }else{
                    echo "Help! An unvalid function has been inserted into my tables. Have I been hacked?";
                }
                $matches = mb_ereg_search_regs();//get next result
            }while($matches);
        }
        echo $reference;
    }
}
```

This way I can decide which functions it is possible to call via the shortcode format and can validate that only integer references can be used.

I am safe now?

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Use some code, like `[func:getURLtoSectionPage:commentId]`, than use some whitelist for allowed functions and arguments and call the function in php...

Comment: In plain PHP, you should be inventing your own limited markup for that, e.g. `foo [url:comment:42] bar` or something along those lines. That can safely be replaced with something like `preg_replace_callback('/\[url:(\w+):(\d+)\]/', ...)`. In Wordpress, I have no real idea, but you may be able to use something like shortcodes.

Comment: I have thought about using a shortcode earlier, and decided against it since I'd like to be able to insert custom links in any of my tables, in any cell, and have them resolved dynamically to the correct page. For example, I'd like to be able to redirect links based on the functions that I call. So that I can update my functions when I change things instead of updating all the comments. But I think I have solved it by combining your hints with output buffering, which lets me dynamically replace internal links anywhere by using shortcodes. Do you think the updated solution is safe to use?

Answer (score 0):

Don't store the code in the database, store the ID, then process it when you need to. BTW, I'm assuming you *really* need it to be dynamic, and you can't just store the final URL.

So, I'd change your example comment-field text to something like:

```
This is a magnificent comment. You should also check out <a href="#comment-47">this other section</a> for more information
```

Then, when you need to display that text, do *something like* a regular expression search-replace on `'href="#comment-([0-9]+)"'`, calling your `getURLtoSectionPage()` function *at that point*.

Does that make sense?

Comment: It makes a lot of sense now that you explained it. I have decided on a different format, but kept your idea.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want to do this by using eval(), and I have not been able to accomplish this by using output buffers either. I would be grateful for any hints as to how I can get this working as safely and cleanly as possible. I do not wish to execute any custom php code, only make function calls to my already existing functions which validates input parameters.

Eval is a terrible approach, as is allowing people to submit raw PHP at all. It's highly error-prone and the results of an error could be catastrophic (and that's without even considering the possibly that code designed by a malicious attacker gets submitted).

You *need* to use something custom. Possibly something inspired by [BBCode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode).

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I am aware that eval() is strongly discouraged, and that was the reason for me not wanting to use it in the first place. I need to be able to link to different sections of my page dynamically, so it would be nice to just insert php code directly, but I do not want to compromise safety. Your tips about BBCode and  Pavel Třupeks tips about shortcode helped me with my first attempt at a solution